# HTTP headers problem

Tags: asp-classic

I'me getting the following error:

```
Response object error 'ASP 0156 : 80004005'

Header Error

/includes/page_language.asp, line 3

The HTTP headers are already written to the client browser. Any HTTP header modifications must be made before writing page content.
```

But, the 1st line of the page is the doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The next line is:

```
<!-- #include file = "includes/page_language.asp" -->
```

The 1st 4 lines in the page_language.asp file are:

```
<%
response.codePage = 65001
response.charset = "utf-8"
%>
```

So it doesn't like *response.charset = "utf-8"* - but there is no HTML before these lines to cause the problem...

This error only happens the 1st time you load a page - press refresh when this has happened and the page loads fine. The site was working properly, but we noticed this yesterday.

UPDATE:
I've now changed index.asp to read:

```
<%
response.codePage = 65001
response.charset = "utf-8"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

But I'm still getting the error at the response.charset line....
I'm stumped - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Finally fixed by removing the response.charset="utf-8" and adding <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed by removing the response.charset="utf-8" and adding

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use firebug and test response.charset. Look's like it is
not `HTTP Content-Type charset` but `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`